# How to 'putObject' to private S3 bucket with a presigned URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried to upload an image to a private S3 bucket which has a pre signed url as below and gave the full S3 access permission to the lambda IAM role too.

```
const S3 = new aws.S3({
      s3ForcePathStyle: true,
      endpoint: 's3BucketUrl',
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
    });

const s3params = {
      Bucket: 's3ImagesBucketName',
      Key: fileName,
      Body: buf, // base64 image data
      ContentEncoding: 'base64',
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
      ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control',
    };

S3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3params, (err, url) => {
      if (err == null) {
        logger.info('SignedUrl -> ', url);

        const options = {
          method: 'PUT',
          url: url,
        };
        request(options, (err, res, body) => {
          if (err == null) {
            logger.info('no errors occurred!', body);
          }
        });

      } else {
        logger.error('Error ', err);
      }
    });
```

This throws 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.' error.

Comment: `method: 'POST'`?  Your signed URL is for *PUT*, not *POST*.

Comment: It's my bad it should be 'PUT'.